# Pitest gradle, low coverage due to @Data

Tags: java, spring, code-coverage, pitest

I tried to get a good coverage file in my java spring project, I mean; see where my tests are good and where they are not. But my problem is that @Data generate a lot of function/class that I don't want to test, and just ruin my coverage.

I already search for a solution, but there is nothing to fix my problem. Looks like Jacoco have something to fix my problem but not Pitest. Maybe Im just not taking the problem right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since version [1.2.1](https://github.com/hcoles/pitest/releases/tag/pitest-parent-1.2.1) Pitest ignores any method or class annotated with `Generated`.

You can configure Lombok to add the annotation by adding the following in lombok.config :

```
lombok.addLombokGeneratedAnnotation = true
```